# Banach space inequality

Tags: inequality, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm looking to prove the following inequality

\begin{align}
||\frac{u}{||u||}-\frac{v}{||v||}|| \leq 2||u-v||
\end{align}

where $u$ and $v$ are elements of a Banach space such that $||u||$ and $||v||$ are greater than $1$.

I know that $||\frac{u}{||u||}||=1$ and have also tried using the triangle inequality.

Comment: HAve you tried with the inverse triangle inequality?

Comment: @TitoEliatron Thanks for the hint. The reverse triangle inequality implies that $2|| ||u||-||v|| || < 2||u-v||$, which looks promising. Not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume w.l.o.g that $\|y\|\leq \|x\|$. For convenience set $\|\frac{x}{\|x\|}-\frac{y}{\|y\|}\|=[x,y]$.

First consider the case when $\|y\|\leq (1-\frac{1}{2}[x,y])\|x\|.$  Then
$$\|x\|\leq\|x-y\|+\|y\|\leq\|x-y\|+(1-\frac{1}{2}[x,y])\|x\|,$$
implying, along with our assumption, that
$$[x,y]\leq2\|x-y\|/\|x\|\leq2\|x-y\|.$$
If $\|y\|\geq (1-\frac{1}{2}[x,y])\|x\|$, we have:
\begin{align*}
[x,y]\|x\|&=\|x-\frac{\|x\|y}{\|y\|}\|\\
& =||x-y+\frac{y}{\|y\|}(\|y\|-\|x\|)\|\\
&\leq \|x-y\|+\|y(\frac{\|x\|}{\|y\|}-1)\|\\
&=\|x-y\|+\|x\|-\|y\|\\
&\leq \|x-y\|+\|x\|+(\frac{1}{2}[x,y]-1)\|x\|.
\end{align*}
Rearranging this inequality and using the fact that $\|x\|\geq 1$ completes the proof.